# How to use array_push to generate an array by passing parameter into a function?

Tags: php, arrays

I have searched many ways to figure out how to use array_push() to generate a multidimensional array, but it gives me an error mentioned below.

Here are the function I am trying to use to fill an array

**PHP**

```
$dataoption = array();
$data = array_walk_recursive($_POST, 'test_post');
function test_post($value, $key)
{
   // sanitize the array elememts
   $valueSAN = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);  
   $keySAN = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $key);
   // generate new array   Key -> value
line 17>>     array_push($dataoption, $keySAN, $valueSAN );
 }
```

ERROR

> **Warning**:  array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in **/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/globalbuy/en/product_detail/ajax/submitform.php** on line **17**

the result must be something like :

```
(Color) (Red)
(Size) (43)
(Quantity) (2)
```

when I change the function to :

```
function test_post($value, $key)
{
  // sanitize the array elememts
  $valueSAN = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $value);
  $keySAN = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $key);
  // generate new array   Key -> value
  line 17>>   $optSELECT[$keySAN] = $valueSAN;
  line 18>>   echo json_encode ($optSELECT);
}
```

I'll have `{"Color":"Red"}{"Size":"43"}{"Quantity":"2"}` which is correct.

The problem with the second result is that, `$optSELECT` seems not be an array, I can't have any access to for example `$optSELECT[0][0]`, `echo $optSELECT[0][0]` will give me nothing.

How can I use array_push() generate an array look a like `{"Color":"Red"}{"Size":"43"}{"Quantity":"2"}`?

I have searched and tried many ways to solve my problem but I wasn't able to fix it.

Comment: Oh, *Magic_quotas. Forever.* Please, use prepared statement instead of escaping everything.

Comment: @sectus use prepared statement? like escape_string ? but $_POST is an array

Comment: What is the objective of escaping everything?

Comment: All I need is to have the array, then I insert them into the DB $_POST contains my form elements. won't array_walk_recursive traverse  $_POST array to allow me sanitize the parsed elements ?

Comment: And i hope you noticed, that you gave the first value to array_push, what is not defined anywhere

Comment: @LeventeNagy How shall I change or modify my function ? As my understanding (Color) (Red) are the first values

Comment: You're not asking for us to generate an array, but an array of objects, or so it seems. Are you trying to turn your Array into `JSON` for client-side processing or something?